# Issues when using extended asm in C on Mac M1

Tags: c, assembly, apple-m1, inline-assembly, arm64

I'm trying to use extended assembly on MacOS (Apple M1). I run into a very un-understandable issue, here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 0;

    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", b);

    asm (
        " mov x1, x1"
        : "=r" (b)
        : "r" (a));

    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result of it :

```
❯ make && ./hello_world_asm
gcc    -c -o hello_world_asm.o hello_world_asm.c
gcc -Wall hello_world_asm.c -o hello_world_asm
1
0
1
1
```

How is that possible? I really don't get it. I don't even use the registers bounded to a and b but still, b is taking a's value.

I tried to change the inner assembly, if I don't directly put any value in the %0 (b bounded register), it'll just take a's.

Comment: Output arguments must be written to. The `=r(b)` tells the compiler that a new value for `b` will be in whatever register it has chosen for that argument. It just so happens that `1` is in that register and since you don't change it, that's what you get.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to change this behavior ? Or a good documentation explaining it ? Can’t find anything relevant (not too complicated not too simple)

Comment: You can change `=` to `+` to make it a read-write operand. It's explained in the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#OutputOperands).

Comment: Note that if you overwrite other registers, you have to declare them as clobbered.

Comment: It's typical for GCC to pick the same register for a write-only and read-only operand, if it doesn't need the input C variable later.  This is an unoptimized build, so it's not keeping anything in registers from this statement to the next.  Output operands are by default assumed *not* to be early-clobber, i.e. written only after reading all inputs, like when wrapping a single instruction.